# RCA shocking myste

Tags: ground, grounding, induction, shock, rca

I got a zap from the shield of a RCA cable from my TV to DVD player(both TV and DVD do not have a ground terminal on the outlet plug).

I measured the metal case to ground and I got a reading of 50V. Amps were very low in the micro( I cannot recall what it was). When I grounded it the problem goes away.

My question, is this just an induction problem and grounding will be sufficient and safe? or possibly a circuit board failure?

I've read a bunch of forms and I cannot find anything that specifically answers this question. I currently have everything disconnected for safety until I solve this.

Comment: Which device does the 50V come from? Disconnect either end of the cable in turn and test. What type of power supply does the device have?

Comment: The 50V is on the shielding and metal frame. It doesn't matter which device for example: If the TV is plugged in but not turned on and RCA not connected  to DVD (floating on one end) I still read 50V and the same is with the DVD. RCA seem to carry 50V regardless of where it is plugged into.

Comment: I would treat it as a hot-ground fault in either the TV or DVD, until you know otherwise.  Assume it is capable of killing you.

Answer (score 1):

With ungrounded plugs, that tends to be normal, and most likely the device manuals say you are supposed to unplug devices while performing connections so you should not be performing connections while they are plugged to mains.

The likely cause with ungrounded devives with 2-prong mains plugs is a EMI capacitor between unisolated mains side and isolated low voltage side.

As a multimeter has very high impedance, it does not load the voltage down so it is not unreasonable to measure 50V. However current will be very small, most likely within allowable limits.

What makes it dangerous is that it can scare you and you injure yourself. Another thing is, when devices are plugged to mains, and you connect it to another device, the RCA or whatever cable signal pins connect first before ground and the voltage differece and the charge stored in the capacitance can often damage the equipment. Therefore cables should not be connected while powered, unless you know what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds likely to be an EMI filter capacitor voltage.

There are 3 capacitors in a mains EMI filter. 1 across the phases that doesn't cause much in this situation, and 1 between each phase and the earth pin.

These 2 capacitors form a capacitive divider if there is no earth provided to the device. As most countries have earth and neutral tied at the power box, the voltage tends to measure about half mains at a small current.

In this case grounding the device exterior is what I would believe is the correct approach.

Comment: This answer does not apply as they have ungrounded mains plugs, like most TVs and DVD players have.

Comment: An ungrounded device may still have these emi capacitors. Just to the chassis. Other things that can cause it is the chassis tied to the circuit board ground. You have a similar effect with a different EMI capacitor that might be fitted over a transformer in an isolated power supply design. This also couples a small amount of mains to that chassis. In either case it should be safety rated capacitors. If it was anything other than half mains. I might be worried.

Comment: No a device that is meant to be ungrounded would not have filter capacitors from live and neutral to chassis that is ungrounded. Indeed it is more likely that there is an EMI cap between mains and secondary side, but you did not mention that in your answer. Also connecting this equpment to other equipment that is grounded would cause the filter current to flow via e.g. RCA cable shield. However otherwise modifying the device to be grounded is not intended use of the device.

Comment: If it is a EMI cap failure could it cause the other devices EMI cap to fail as well?

Comment: Nothing indicates EMI cap failure. It is there by design due to regulations regarding EMI.